# Passing an array of strings to a procedure and using it in the WHERE clause with IN

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to pass a list of strings to a procedure and use it in the WHERE clause of a select statement, but I can't figure out how to do this.

I have declared the following nested table:

```
TYPE t_strarray IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
```

The procedure looks as follows:

```
PROCEDURE getstuff(p_list IN t_strarray, io_cursor OUT t_cursor)
   IS    
   BEGIN
        OPEN io_cursor FOR
            SELECT * FROM mytable 
            WHERE mytable.field1 in (select * from table(p_list)); 
   END;
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your array needs to be a SQL object type, created directly in SQL, not a PLSQL type declared in a package:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_strarray IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
  2  /
Type created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE mytable (field1 VARCHAR2(30));
Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('A');
1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('D');
1 row created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getstuff(p_list IN t_strarray,
  2                                       io_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
  3  BEGIN
  4     OPEN io_cursor FOR
  5        SELECT *
  6          FROM mytable
  7         WHERE mytable.field1 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(p_list));
  8  END;
  9  /
Procedure created.

SQL> VARIABLE cc REFCURSOR;
SQL> EXEC getstuff (t_strarray('A', 'B', 'C'), :cc);    
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print cc

FIELD1
------------------------------
A
```

Comment: +1 It's annoying that we still have to do this but alas we do.